# user location returns a string: "Array" Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
$user_location = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

echo " Location: " . $user_location['location'];
```

The code above is returning "Location: Array". Is this a Facebook API problem or does this require specific permissions?

Comment: A `var_dump($user_location)` should show you exactly what that variable contains.

Answer (score 1):

You have to print like this-

```
print_r($user_location['location']);

// location name
echo " Location: " . $user_location['location']['name'];
```